# No Google apps and no install zip option in recovery mode

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a galaxy s3 and I put CyanogenMod on it but there are no google apps and when I boot into recovery mode there is no install zip option to install the gapp ROM how do I get the Google apps on there

Comment: Which recovery are you using?

Comment: If you're on Cyanogen recovery, Go to _Apply update_ -> _Choose from sdcard0_ -> _`gapps.zip`_

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your recovery got broken, Now you'll have to flash another one the same way you did the first one, via Odin, and i recommend you this version,

> [CWM_Touch_6.0.4.4_with_Odin](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_1zjuazXSqbd2lCNnFET21fWG8/edit)

After you flash the recovery, Boot into it, Then select the "GAPPS" version that is compatible with the ROM version you've installed, If you don't have it, Just choose the compatible one from this thread

> [GAPPS_ALL_VER](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/pa-gapps-continuation-t3098071)

Once you flash GAPPS, you're done.